# Issue when Parse string to ulong in c# getting format exception [Input string was not in correct format]

Tags: c#, .net

in my code i have assigned and long value to string variable and when i try to parse it it throws and exception

```
Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
   at System.UInt64.Parse(String s)
   at Program.Main()
Command terminated by signal 6
```

and my code is here

```
string data = "‭‭071926809";
Console.WriteLine(ulong.Parse(data));
```

Also i already tried **Tryparse** and also checked with directly assigning value to the 1st parameter to the **Parse** like below it is working fine

```
Console.WriteLine(ulong.Parse("071926809"));
```

which is working fine as it is handling the exception but in this case it is assigning **0** to the variable but what i am expecting is if i have assigned the some known Long or integer value to the string varibale and then trying to convert why it is still giving Exception Can any one tell?

Comment: I removed the asp.met.mvc, c#-4.0 and c#-5.0 tags as your question is not related to these topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string starts with two invisible characters U+202D (Left-to-Right Override). You can see this with the following code:

```
string data = "‭‭071926809";
foreach (var c in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:X4}", (int)c);
}
```

Result:

```
202D
202D
0030
0037
0031
0039
0032
0036
0038
0030
0039
```

The best way to fix this is to make sure your data contains digits only in the first place. If not possible, clean it up before parsing, e.g. if you know U+202D is the only character that might interfere, `data.Trim('\u202D')`,